# Design and unit-test cross-platform application

Tags: go

I'm working on a project that builds for windows (currently) and will be built for darwin in future.

Here is a quick overview:

file1.go:

```
package management

type Manager interface {
    Action1()
}
```

file2_windows.go:

```
package management

type WinManager struct {
    some configs
}

func (WinManager) Action1() {
   ...
}

func InitWinManager() WinManager {
    create and return inited WinManager with configs
}
```

handler.go:

```
package handle

func handle() {
    ...

    var m Manager
    if runtime.GOOS = "windows" {
        m = InitWinManager()
    }

    ... 
}
```

**Q1:** How to correctly avoid such conditional initialization of the Manager for specific OS?

Few words about CI - since our build machine runs on linux and I need an .exe file I build it like that:

1. create versioninfo.json with version specific properties and name of the executable
2. run `GOOS=windows go generate` on main.go with `//go:generate goversioninfo`
3. run `GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 go build -o application.exe`

It builds just fine and I don't have any troubles with it.

Another problem come up with `go test ./handle`. Before running actual test it tries to compile tested package, but it fails to find `InitWinManager()` method since my build machine's OS is different from windows.

So **Q2:** How to specify an OS version to run for in `go test`?

Comment: Use [build constraints](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Build_Constraints).

Comment: @Flimzy it's not really what I'm looking for, build constraints ignored if suffixes are present in OS specific files.. And still there is a common `handle` which needs to be built for multiply OSes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place the Windows specific code in file2_windows.go. This file is built for Windows targets only.

```
package management

type Manager struct {
    ... Windows specific type
}

func (Manager) Action1() {
   ... Windows specific code
}

func InitManager() Manager {
    create and return inited Manager with configs
}
```

Place the Darwin specific code in file2_darwin.go. This file is built for Darwin targets only.

```
package management

type Manager struct {
    ... Darwin specific type
}

func (Manager) Action1() {
   ... Darwin specific code
}

func InitManager() Manager {
    create and return inited Manager with configs
}
```

Call InitManager from the Handler function:

```
m := InitManager()
```

This calls the Darwin version on a Darwin target and the Windows version on a Windows target.

The above uses the file name convention for setting [build constraints](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Build_Constraints).  It's also possible to specify the constraints using comments. Use

```
// +build windows
```

to specify that the containing file is only built for a Windows target and

```
// +build darwin
```

to specify that the containing file is only built for a Darwin target.

I assumed that you defined Manager as a common interface for the Windows and Darwin specific managers.  Because only one manager is built into the code at a time, there's no need to define an interface for this purpose.  If there's some other reason that the interface is needed, change type types used above to ManagerImpl or something like that.

Q2: It's not possible to run `go test` for a target system that's different from the current system.

Comment: So, consider adding a `linux` target.

Comment: @MichaelHampton For linux, follow the pattern for the other targets: put the Linux specific code in file2_linux.go.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Thanks! So to cover cross-platform components I need to write OS specific tests and setup OS specific build machines to run it?

Comment: @MichaelHampton yeah, but I don't really want to add something that won't be used right now and in the future.. Do you mean kind of mock for `linux` target?

Comment: @mucc Your CI build server runs Linux. Having Linux code means it can actually run your (non-OS-specific) tests.

Comment: @CeriseLimón About `Manager` interface, I wanted to limit and strictly define actions that must be added for the future when someone will be adding `darwin` implementation

Comment: @MichaelHampton I understand that, so if the project has a lot of OS specific code, it should be covered and tested on every particular target.

Comment: @mucc  You can run non-OS specific tests on any OS.  Run tests with OS specific code on that particular OS.

Answer (score 2):

I think build flags are going to be your friend here.

Is there any reason to be compiling the Darwin version of the Manager into your Windows executable? Probably not, so why even reference it? The same goes vice-versa.

You can tell go build/test to only build a file if $GOOS is Windows by putting the following line at the top of the file...

```
// +build windows
```

This means the file will be totally ignored when building on Darwin.

How is this useful to you? Well, instead of implementing two Manager types, you can implement the same one two different ways! Like this...

windowsmanager.go

```
// +build windows

package management

type MyManager struct {
    some configs
}

func (MyManager) PlatformGnosticAction1() {
   ...
}

func InitMyManager() MyManager {
    create and return inited windows version of MyManager with configs
}
```

Similarly, for Darwin

darwinmanager.go

```
// +build darwin

package management

type MyManager struct {
    some configs
}

func (MyManager) PlatformGnosticAction1() {
   ...
}

func InitMyManager() MyManager {
    create and return inited darwin version of MyManager with configs
}
```

Now, only one version of the MyManager is ever compiles, so the code which calls it doesn't need to be aware of the difference...

handler.go

```
package handle

func handle() {
    ...

    m := InitMyManager()

    ... 
}
```

Tags impact if *files* are compiled or not, so if there's a lot of common code between darwinmanager.go and windowsmanager.go you might want to refactor so as much of that common code as possible out of your tagged files, but in the same package. E.G.

mymanager.go

```
package Manager

func (m *MyManager) APlatformAgnosticFunc() {
    ...
}


func (m *MyManager) AnotherPlatformAgnosticFunc() {
    ...
}
```

While keeping the platform gnostic stuff in the tagged files.

You can apparently do similar things with file suffixes, but I've never tried that. Dave Cheney, wrote a much more thorough blog on the topic, you can read that [here](https://dave.cheney.net/2013/10/12/how-to-use-conditional-compilation-with-the-go-build-tool).

Hope that helps!

M

Comment: Yeah, as for me using suffixes better describes particular file unless you want to build it for specific architecture, e.g. 32/64 bit OS or code is the same for few OSes. Anyway thanks for the info!