# Go cross-platform tests

Tags: unit-testing, go, cross-platform

## Problem description

I've developed a CLI in Go. My dev environment is Linux. I wrote unit-tests and only produce releases of executable files when tests pass. When I test or use my tool in a Linux environment, everything works fine.

My CI/CD pipeline is built around goreleaser to produce multi-platform executables. Since my app doesn't use exotic cross-platform functionalities, I was quite confident that windows executable should work as expected. But it didn't.

Long story short, always normalize paths with `filepath.ToSlash()`. But this is not my question.

## Question

Hence my question is: "since behavior might change on different platforms for such little mistakes, is it possible to run `go test` for a list of os/architecture ?" I can't imagine rebooting on windows to test every commit manually and I don't think discipline is the answer. If it was, we wouldn't test things at all.

## Search attempts

A fast search on Google and Stack Overflow for "golang cross-platform tests" didn't return any results. Am I missing something or is my approach to this problem wrong ?

## Fist edit

Most comments pointed out that the only way to test the behavior of an executable on a given platform is... to test it on this platform (in a multi-stage CI/CD for example). This is so obvious that there might not be a way to achieve it otherwise, I know.

But triggering a parallel CI/CD job on every platform for every commit (of partially untested code) doesn't sound satisfying to me. It IS the only way to know for sure that the code behave as expected on every targeted platform but I'm wondering if anyone stumbled on this issue and found a pre-CI/CD solution to this problem.

Comment: This isn't Go specific. Get an account on a CI system that offers multiple platforms and run your tests once per platform. Which service to use if off topic here, but a simple search should get you what you need.

Comment: Great question. I would be interested in an answer as well. The only solution I can think of at the moment is to write unit tests and run them on your CI. Some CIs (like Github Actions) allow you to choose a runner with a different OS. So you create some tests and run them on a linux and on a windows runner. Then you should be able to find problems earlier.

Comment: You can only test platform-specific behavior on that specific platform, because most platform-specific behavior is tied to platform-specific system calls, which require that system to be present in order to call it.

Comment: A lot of common sense in those comments: "you want to test the behavior on a platform ? Then test it on this platform !". Though it might be the only way to get conclusive test results, it implies triggering CI/CD with parallel tests on each platform. 

I was looking for some solution on the developer machine, before committing untested code. I can't think of a good way to do it though. I will continue searching and answer the question if I find something.

By the way, I think it is a real problem, even if it might not have a lightweight solution. Does the question really deserves a -1 ?

Answer (score 0):

> Though it might be the only way to get conclusive test results, it implies triggering CI/CD with parallel tests on each platform. I was looking for some solution on the developer machine, before committing untested code

You can install a local CICD tool which would, on (local) commit, trigger those tests.
A Local GitLab, for instance, can [run test in multiple platforms simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52031860/6309) (since [GitLab 11.5](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2018/11/22/gitlab-11-5-released/#access-control-for-pages))
But that implies at least a Docker image in order to test on Windows from your Linux dev environment.

With Go alone however, as mentioned in "[Design and unit-test cross-platform application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48896657/6309)"

> It's not possible to run go test for a target system that's different from the current system.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to test a different CPU architecture, you should be able to do it with QEMU. [This blog post](https://ctrl-c.us/posts/test-goarch.html) explains how.

If you are trying to test a different OS, you can probably do everything you need to do in Docker containers. You could use a tool like VSCode’s remote development toolkit to easily dev/build/test a project in a specific container, or you could write a custom Makefile that calls the appropriate Docker commands when you run `make test` (allowing you to run tests in multiple OSes with one command).